# 2 title bars are coming in xamarin form app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

2 tile bars are coming in my xamarin forms app, where

1. Bar 1 contains back button(left side) and logout button(right side)
2. Bar 2 contains Content page title(left side) and logout button(right
   side)

I want to merge them into single title bar. My code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LIS.Pages.SampleCollectionList"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:LIS.View;assembly:LIS" Title="Test">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="SearchItem" Icon="logout.png" Priority="0" Clicked="SearchItem_Clicked"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <Grid>
       .....
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q0eM.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem, could you please share more code  a basic demo to reproduce this problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 2 title bars are coming in xamarin form app

If you use `NavigationPage` to manage the navigation of a stack of other pages, when you navigate to another `Page`, don't create a new `NavigationPage`, just Push a new page onto the existing  `NavigationPage`.

For example, if you set `MainPage` like this :

```
MainPage =  new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

When you navigate to the second page, if you create a new `NavigationPage` :

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Page1()));
```

In this situation, you will have  two title bars in your app, effect  :

[image]

**Solution :**

Just Push the new page onto the existing  `NavigationPage` :

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
```

Effect :

[image]